# How to show tab bar in all views

Tags: ios

Following is my code and it is showing tab bar only on given 2 tab bar items but it is not showing tab bar in other views.

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.startQuizViewController = [[StartQuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.scoreViewController = [[ScoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

self.startQuizViewController.title = @"QUIZ";
self.scoreViewController.title = @"SCORES";

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.startQuizViewController,self.scoreViewController,nil];

_navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

code in written in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m.`

Comment: You can easily do all this without code using `storyboards`. And it will also solve your problem too.

Comment: i am using interface builder please suggest for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
UIViewController  *viewController1, *viewController2;

    viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1] ;

    viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] ;
 UINavigationController *navigationcontroller2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2] ;


    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationcontroller, navigationcontroller2, nil];
```

and finally

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

This way you have seperate navigation controllers for both tabbar controller.

Answer (score 1):

change this part:

```
_navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

to this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

you cannot have tabbarcontroller inside a navigation controller. so just remove navigation controller and set tab bar controller as root view controller

edit:

```
self.startQuizViewController = [[StartQuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.scoreViewController = [[ScoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

self.startQuizViewController.title = @"QUIZ";
self.scoreViewController.title = @"SCORES";

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UINavigationController * nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.startQuizViewController];

UINavigationController * nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.scoreViewController];


self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nil];


self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

that's it. you can now push view controller inside those controller and can have the tab bar always there.

Comment: but when i did so it didnt showed the expected output

Comment: also i want to show navigation bar and tab bar both in my app

Comment: don't you want the tab bar be the root view controller? if you want to navigation inside each tab, then you should put your controller(self.startQuizViewController) inside a navigation controller. then add the navigation controller to to tab bar.

Comment: can you code it down for me because i am bit confused right now.